# What useful information can I extract from the F# interactive timing output?

Tags: performance, f#, garbage-collection, timing, f#-interactive

While learning F#, occasionally I write several variants of an algorithm (with the same asymptotic complexity) for fun. But in the end, I also want some insight which one I want to keep using or improving on.

So I use the F# interactive with the `#time` command. The obvious decision criterion is of course the time it takes to complete some task. But I get additional info which I suspect has to do with garbage collection statistics. But I don't really know what to make of that.

Here are some example timings of three permutation algorithms:

```
> let len = 10
> let last _ = // some way of knowing all have been seen (i.e. counting)
> let a = [|1..len|]

> a |> grayPermutations |> Seq.find last |> printfn "%A"
> [|2; 1; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
Real: 00:00:13.323, CPU: 00:00:13.343, GC gen0: 763, gen1: 762, gen2: 1

> a |> permutations |> Seq.find last |> printfn "%A"
> [|10; 9; 8; 7; 6; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1|]
Real: 00:00:00.631, CPU: 00:00:00.625, GC gen0: 138, gen1: 138, gen2: 0

> a |> findPermutation last |> printfn "%A"
> [|10; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9|]
Real: 00:00:04.400, CPU: 00:00:04.390, GC gen0: 385, gen1: 385, gen2: 0
```

The winner is quite clear, but what does the stuff after the timings tell me? And can (or should) I try to optimize for this—given I know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from the [`#time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx) directive outputs real time, cpu time and garbage collection info where you can see the number of garbage collection operations in all three generations of [managed heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#generations)

> **Generation 0**.  This is the youngest generation and contains short-lived objects. An example of a short-lived object is a temporary
>   variable. Garbage collection occurs most frequently in this
>   generation. Newly allocated objects form a new generation of objects
>   and are implicitly generation 0 collections, unless they are large
>   objects, in which case they go on the large object heap in a
>   generation 2 collection. Most objects are reclaimed for garbage
>   collection in generation 0 and do not survive to the next generation.
>
> **Generation 1**. This generation contains short-lived objects and serves as a buffer between short-lived objects and long-lived objects.
>
> **Generation 2**. This generation contains long-lived objects. An example of a long-lived object is an object in a server application
>   that contains static data that is live for the duration of the
>   process.

On a side note, evaluating algorithms strictly on execution time is flawed as you can have one approach that runs in O(n) time and another one that runs in O(n2) time but the difference between them only manifests for large inputs.

Comment: +1; I would add another problem with using execution time is that it is not deterministic.  The same is true (perhaps more so) for the FSI-reported garbage collector information.

Comment: Thanks. First, of course I only compare the same asymptotic complexities (question updated). Second, can I deduce something hinting optimization potential? Like “Big gen0 number is bad, try to keep objects around.”

Comment: @phoog: I try to use reasonably large inputs to get quite stable timings. But I didn't watch out for GC fluctuations so far—interesting point. But as long as I don't know what to make of it…